# Javascript restrict text field to numbers and decimals?

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I've tried a few solutions here but all of them boil down to removing the non-numeric input after the input is put in.

This solution here works for numbers:
https://jsfiddle.net/HkEuf/17470/

But it doesn't allow decimals.

I've to edit it as follows but it still won't allow for decimals:

```js
    $(document).ready(function () {
      //called when key is pressed in textbox
    
          $("#quantity").keypress(function (e) {
             //if the letter is not digit then display error and don't type anything
             if (e.which != 110 && e.which != 190 && e.which != 8 && e.which != 0 && (e.which < 48 || e.which > 57 )) {
                //display error message
                $("#errmsg").html("Digits Only").show().fadeOut("slow");
                       return false;
            }
           });
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="quantity" id="quantity" />
```

Comment: If you allow users to input a decimal separator, you'll have to add two more rules: 1. Input can ony have one decimal separator, 2. Input can't end with a decimal separator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here I've added some code in your jsfiddle reference to allow decimal number and prevent user to enter "." symbol twice. Here's the complete code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
//called when key is pressed in textbox
  $("#quantity").keypress(function (e) {
        var tempInput = $("#quantity").val()
            if(tempInput.split(".").length >= 2 && e.which == 46)
                return false;  //To check whether user has entered dot symbol before
             //if the letter is not digit then display error and don't type anything
             if (e.which != 110 && e.which != 46 && e.which != 190 && e.which != 8 && e.which != 0 && (e.which < 48 || e.which > 57)) {
                //display error message
                $("#errmsg").html("Digits Only").show().fadeOut("slow");
                       return false;
            }
   });
});
```

If anything goes wrong, feel free to ask.

P.S : I assume that you use "." symbol to represent float number

Answer (score 2):

You could do this all with HTML, all you need to do is use the [number type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/number) with a `step` attribute like this.

- **Note 1:** By adding the `required` attribute we can validate the field on submit otherwise it won't be validated unless there is input within the field.
- **Note 2:** the number type also supports `min` and `max`
- **Note 3:** Supports IE 10+ and all other major browsers

```html
<form>
  <input type="number" step="0.001" name="quantity" id="quantity" required>
  <p><input type="submit" value="Numbers Only!"></p>
</form>
```

### Prevent "E" key

We can block the `e` key with a `keydown` event and if `e.key == 'e'` we can prevent the key:

```js
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('[type=number]')).forEach(i => {
  i.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
    if(e.key == 'e') e.preventDefault()
  })
})
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="number" step="0.001" name="quantity" id="quantity" required>
  <p><input type="submit" value="Numbers Only!"></p>
</form>
```

Comment: This still allows the the input for the 'e' key on my keyboard.

Comment: I have added a second snippet to prevent the `e` key from getting pressed

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    //called when key is pressed in textbox

    $("#quantity").keypress(function (e) {
         // If it's not a digit then display error and don't type anything
         if (e.which == 46 || e.which == 8 || e.which == 0 || (e.which > 48 && e.which < 57 )) {
             // Validate count of decimal separators
             var dSCount = ($(this).val().match(/\./g) || []).length;
             if (e.which == 46 && dSCount > 0) {
                 // Display error message
                 $("#errmsg").html("Only one decimal separator allowed").show().fadeOut("slow");
                 return false;
             }
        } else {
            // Display error message
            $("#errmsg").html("Digits Only").show().fadeOut("slow");
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

There is a chance that the input ends with a dot, you'll have to validate that too (you could simply remove the trailing decimal separator before the form submission).